# Obtener una consulta a partir de 2 tablas

Tags: mysql, laravel

una consulta tengo 2 tablas, una llamada secciones que contiene un campo tipo varchar c(150), donde guardo los codigos de las materias que pertenecen a dicha seccion, ejemplo '001002003004005', el codigo de las materias ocupa 3 digitos, tengo otra tabla llamada materias con los campos codmat c(3), nombremat c(100), ejemplo
001 matematicas
002 castellano
003 geografia

ahora lo que quiero obtener en una consulta con dos campos, codigo y nombre, donde esten los codigos que tengo en el campo de la tabla secciones con sus respectivos nombres, de antemano gracias

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Sin animo de ofender,NI de decirte como deberías programar. Puedo sugerirte que cuando creas las tablas de la base de datos, te tomes el tiempo para realizar un buen diagnostico de las necesidades y diseñar tu base de datos de la mejor manera , siguiendo las "Buenas Prácticas de Diseño de Base de Datos" .

Un ejemplo de eso seria que en las tablas secundarias existan campos que sirvan como llaves externas (FOREIGN KEY) que hagan referencia a las llaves principales de las tablas primarias. (PRIMARY KEY).

De esta manera las relaciones son mas fáciles de realizar para el motor de base de datos y mas rápidas.

En tu caso en la tabla secciones debería existir un campo  "cod_materia" o "rela_codmat"  o algo así donde se guarde justamente el código de la materia. y desde ese campo se puede realizar mejor la relacion con la tabla materias.

Dicho esto. Vamos a lo que nos interesa

Si es en lenguaje SQL

```
     SELECT secciones.codigo , materias.nombremat
        
        FROM  secciones 

        LEFT JOIN materias ON 
          
        SUBSTRING(secciones.codigo,1,3) = materias.codmat
```

Si es con Laravel Eloquent

```
        use DB;
        
        use App\Models\Seccion;    //supuestamente el modelo de secciones
        use App\Models\Materia;    // supuestamente el modelo de materias

        $Secciones = Seccion::join('materias',DB::raw('SUBSTRING(secciones.codigo, 1, 3)'),
       '=' , 'materias.codmat)
       ->get();
```

la clase DB y el metodo raw, DB::raw(), permiten especificar lenguaje SQL directo en Eloquent.

La funcion SUBSTRING() de mysql  permite extraer una parte de un String pasado como
parametro

Espero que te ayude. Saludos

Comment: buen dia, disculpen si no me di a entender, es un sistema que estoy modificando,esta en laravel con mysql, la tabla secciones tiene un campo donde guarda ls codigos de todas las materias (puede tener hasta 15 materias), como lo explique ejemplo si una seccion tiene 5 materias el campo quedaria asi '021042031675231' donde 021,042,031,675,231 son los codigos de las materias, lo que yo quiero es obtener una tabla con esos codigos mas el nombre de la materia que esta en la tabla materias

Answer (score 0):

Gregorio Nava

Existen varias posibilidades para resolver tu problema, pero creo que podrías hacer lo siguiente.

1. Recuperas el código que te interesa , por ejemplo 021042031675231.
2. Separar los códigos de a tres caracteres y los guardas en una matriz de códigos
   (valga la redundancia).
3. Con esos códigos, buscas las materias que corresponden

Tu programa quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
      use App\Models\Seccion;    //supuestamente el modelo de secciones
      use App\Models\Materia;    // supuestamente el modelo de materias

      //suponemos que ya tienes el código que te interesa
      //sino deberías ver la manera de obtenerlo de la tabla de 
      //secciones

      $codigo = "021042031675231";  // código de ejemplo    

      //creo una matriz 

      $codigosMaterias = [];

      //recorro $codigo y extraigo la parte que me interesa
      // y lo guardo en la matriz

      for($pos = 0 ; $pos< strlen($codigo) ; $pos = pos + 3 ) 
      {
         $codigosMaterias[] = substr($codigo , $pos , 3);
   
      }

      //busco las materias

      $materias = Materia::whereIn('codmat', $codigosMaterias)->get();
```

En la variable $materias . deberías tener lo que estas necesitando

Saludos